# There is no enough input tensors

Tags: tensorflow2.0

```
x_train, y_train = train_generator.next()
x_test, y_test = test_generator.next()
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Input

input_shape=(256,256,3)
model1_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
model1 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu')(model1_input)
model1 = MaxPooling2D(2,2)(model1)
model1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu')(model1)
model1 = MaxPooling2D(2,2)(model1)
model1_output = Flatten()(model1)
input_shape=(256,256,3)
model2_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
model2 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu')(model2_input)
model2 = MaxPooling2D(2,2)(model2)
model2 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu')(model2)
model2 = MaxPooling2D(2,2)(model2)
model2_output = Flatten()(model2)
from keras.layers import Concatenate
merge = Concatenate()([model1_output, model2_output])
x = Dense(15, activation='softmax')(merge)
from keras.models import Model
final_model = Model(inputs=[model1, model2], outputs=x)
#compile
final_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
final_model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_3 (InputLayer)           [(None, 62, 62, 64)  0           []                               
                                ]                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 input_4 (InputLayer)           [(None, 62, 62, 32)  0           []                               
                                ]                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 flatten (Flatten)              (None, 246016)       0           ['input_3[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 flatten_1 (Flatten)            (None, 123008)       0           ['input_4[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 concatenate (Concatenate)      (None, 369024)       0           ['flatten[1][0]',                
                                                                  'flatten_1[1][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)                  (None, 15)           5535375     ['concatenate[1][0]']            
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 5,535,375
Trainable params: 5,535,375
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

but when i want to train the model it shows that input is not enough

```
history = final_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20)
```

```
Epoch 1/20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23332\1563790524.py in <module>
----> 1 history = final_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20)

D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 889, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 200, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Layer "{layer_name}" expects {len(input_spec)} input(s),'

    ValueError: Layer "model" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 256, 256, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

i also tried that give two inputs to the generator but it's also useless